# InvalidConfigException when running yii2 advanced template on windows

Tags: php, docker-compose, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm running code available here under feature-1-login branch:
https://github.com/dzidlicious/invest-tracker

After running the docker-compose up and accessing the BACKEND part of the application, I'm getting the following stack trace:

```
yii\base\ErrorException: Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The directory does not exist: ' 

in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php:236

Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(546): yii\web\AssetManager->checkBasePathPermission()
#1 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(478): yii\web\AssetManager->publishDirectory('/app/vendor/yii...', Array)
#2 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetBundle.php(181): yii\web\AssetManager->publish('/app/vendor/yii...', Array)
#3 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(292): yii\web\AssetBundle->publish(Object(yii\web\AssetManager))
#4 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(263): yii\web\AssetManager->loadBundle('yii\\validators\\...', Array, true)
#5 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(287): yii\web\AssetManager->getBundle('yii\\validators\\...')
#6 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetBundle.php(125): yii\web\View->registerAssetBundle('yii\\validators\\...')
#7 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/validators/RequiredValidator.php(93): yii\web\AssetBundle::register(Object(yii\web\View))
#8 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/widgets/ActiveField.php(833): yii\validators\RequiredValidator->clientValidateAttribute(Object(common\models\LoginForm), 'username', Object(yii\web\View))
#9 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/widgets/ActiveField.php(233): yii\widgets\ActiveField->getClientOptions()
#10 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/widgets/ActiveField.php(223): yii\widgets\ActiveField->begin()
#11 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4/src/ActiveField.php(244): yii\widgets\ActiveField->render('<label for="log...')
#12 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/widgets/ActiveField.php(176): yii\bootstrap4\ActiveField->render()
#13 /app/backend/views/site/login.php(27): yii\widgets\ActiveField->__toString()
#14 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(348): require('/app/backend/vi...')
#15 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(257): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('/app/backend/vi...', Array)
#16 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(156): yii\base\View->renderFile('/app/backend/vi...', Array, Object(backend\controllers\SiteController))
#17 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(410): yii\base\View->render('login', Array, Object(backend\controllers\SiteController))
#18 /app/backend/controllers/SiteController.php(87): yii\base\Controller->render('login', Array)
#19 [internal function]: backend\controllers\SiteController->actionLogin()
#20 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#22 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): yii\base\Controller->runAction('login', Array)
#23 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(104): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/login', Array)
#24 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#25 /app/backend/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#26 {main} in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php:343
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(256, 'Exception (Inva...', '/app/vendor/yii...', 343, Array)
#1 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(343): trigger_error('Exception (Inva...', 256)
#2 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/widgets/ActiveField.php(178): yii\base\ErrorHandler::convertExceptionToError(Object(yii\base\InvalidConfigException))
#3 /app/backend/views/site/login.php(27): yii\widgets\ActiveField->__toString()
#4 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(348): require('/app/backend/vi...')
#5 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(257): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('/app/backend/vi...', Array)
#6 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(156): yii\base\View->renderFile('/app/backend/vi...', Array, Object(backend\controllers\SiteController))
#7 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(410): yii\base\View->render('login', Array, Object(backend\controllers\SiteController))
#8 /app/backend/controllers/SiteController.php(87): yii\base\Controller->render('login', Array)
#9 [internal function]: backend\controllers\SiteController->actionLogin()
#10 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#12 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(534): yii\base\Controller->runAction('login', Array)
#13 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(104): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/login', Array)
#14 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#15 /app/backend/web/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#16 {main}
```

I have intentionally committed my config files and attached a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: maybe missing dependencies, if you use `composer` try to build and/or refresh your dependencies

Comment: It looks like the error happens because you are missing the `backend/web/assets` folder and the server does not have the permissions to create it. You can create it manually, then update the permissions and give the server group rw permissions, or run `init` on the project root, if you are sure that nothing you have modified will be overwritten.

Comment: @RaulSauco thank you, you are right! it solved the issue!

Comment: @dzdz If it solved your problem, that comment should be an answer, consider [marking it accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or [up-voting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error happens because you are missing the `backend/web/assets` folder and the server does not have the permissions to create it.

Check the owner and permissions of `backend/web` if the server can't write it, it won't be able to create the `assets` folder.

You could update `backend/web` and make it server-writable.

You can also create `backend/web/assets` manually, then update the permissions and give the server group rw permissions, or [run `init`](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#preparing-application) on the project root, if you are sure that nothing you have modified will be overwritten.